# Codeigniter - Pass an array from view to controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

Controller Placeout:

```
$data['placeout']=$this->placeout_model->get_data_list();
$this->load->view('placeout/index',$data);
```

View placeout/index:

```
                    <?php 
                        $i=1;
                        foreach ($placeout as $placeout_item){
                    ?>
                            <tr class="gradeX">
                                <td class="center"><?php echo $i; $i++; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $placeout_item['pjname']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $placeout_item['entries_date']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $placeout_item['lg_id']; ?></td>
                                <td class="right"><?php echo $placeout_item['entries_amt']; ?></td>
                            </tr>
                    <?php 
                        }
                    ?>
```

I want to send '$placeout' array to 'export' Controller (to export '$placeout' array into an excel file). How to send the array and to retrieve the array on 'export' controller? Should i use jquery, ajax or something??
Thank you.

Comment: There's a table class in codeigniter, if this is only a process then no need to put on view , you can do it on controller using codeigniter table class to populate then put it on excel file

Comment: Actually i need to put the array first in the view, then i place a button in the view to export the view table data. Sorry for my bad english & thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can send it through AJAX, but, what is somebody changes content with AJAX?

Wrong data should be exported.

I would rather suggest another approach.

Save export data in a class variable in controller.

Before, sending data to view, loop over it and prepare it for export.

Save it in controller itself.

Comment: Can you give me an example code for that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to generate an array in model function where you prepare the array.